# Custom grouping in xsl

Tags: algorithm, xslt, grouping

Hi I have a problem requiring a rather specialized sort of grouping and would like some feedback on the best approach.
Here is some xml:

```
<root>
  <locations>
    <location>
      <address>123 4 st Smallville</address>
      <number>1</number>
    </location>
    <location>
      <address>432 1 st Metropolis</address>
      <number>2</number>
    </location>
  </locations>
  <insuranceCoverages>
    <coverage>
      <name>General Coverage</name>
      <locationSplits>
        <coverage>
          <name>Building Coverage</name>
          <locationNumber>1</locationNumber>
          <clauses>
            <coverage>
              <name>Earthquake Exclusion</name>
            </coverage>
          </clauses>
        </coverage>
      </locationSplits>
    </coverage>
    <coverage>
      <name>General Liability</name>
    </coverage>
  </insuranceCoverages>
</root>
```

What I'd like to do is group coverages by location into a fairly flat hierarchy. Something like:

```
┌Location 1
├┬Coverage "Building Coverage"
│└Coverage "Earthquake Exclusion"
├Location 2
├No Location
├┬Coverage "General Coverage"
│└Coverage "General Liability"
```

My current solution uses a template on locations/location and enumerates the list of coverages looking for a location number that matches the current location. However, since this algorithm enumerates all coverages for each location, it is

```
O(nm)
  where n = # locations + 1
        m = # coverages
```

I would prefer if my algorithm could be optimized to traverse the tree of coverages only once, placing each coverage into a set based on the current location of itself or it's ancestors, and then printing out those sets.

```
O(n)
  where n = # coverages
```

Of course, if there are more efficient ways of expressing this with xsl, (possibly with the xsl:for-each-group instruction?) I'd be interested in hearing about that too.

Comment: I'd like to add that I'm using version xslt 2.0 but am free to use whichever version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there are more efficient ways of expressing this with xsl,

The efficient way to do this with XSLT is by using a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)**. Here's a simple example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="coverage-by-location" match="coverage" use="locationNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="locations/location">
            <location number="{number}">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('coverage-by-location', number)">
                    <coverage name="{name}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </location>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This traverses only the locations/location branch of the tree, and uses the index created by the `<key>` instruction in order to select the coverages corresponding to the current location.

Adding another branch of "No location" to the output tree is slightly more tricky, but can be done by modifying the key to:

```
<xsl:key name="coverage-by-location" match="coverage" use="string(locationNumber)" />
```

At this point, it will be more convenient to have a single template to handle coverages of both kinds, so:

XSLT **1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="coverage-by-location" match="coverage" use="string(locationNumber)" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="locations/location"/>
        <no-location>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('coverage-by-location', '')"/>
        </no-location>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="location">
    <location number="{number}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('coverage-by-location', number)"/>
    </location>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="coverage">
    <coverage name="{name}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying this to your input example will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <location number="1">
      <coverage name="Building Coverage"/>
   </location>
   <location number="2"/>
   <no-location>
      <coverage name="General Coverage"/>
      <coverage name="Earthquake Exclusion"/>
      <coverage name="General Liability"/>
   </no-location>
</root>
```

which is a bit different from the result you expected, but you did not explain how exactly the "Earthquake Exclusion" coverage would be associated with location #1.

---

**EDIT:**

> As for the Earthquake exclusion, it is important for it to end up
>   under the location 1 element because it is a child of another coverage
>   at location 1.

In such case, I believe it would be best to change the key to:

```
<xsl:key name="coverage-by-location" match="coverage" use="string(ancestor-or-self::coverage/locationNumber)" />
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! I'm curious about the key instruction. Do you know how it works under the hood? It looks like it creates an index. Is that true?
As for the Earthquake exclusion, it is important for it to end up under the location 1 element because it is a child of another coverage at location 1. Can the key be generated to incorporate this requirement?
Also, I should have mentioned in the question: I am using the xsl server side, so I am free to use version 2.0 and beyond. Are there any new features that might help?

Comment: I was able to modify the key command to create its index by checking for a child element locationNumber or an ancestor with child element locationNumber `<xsl:key name="coverage-by-location" match="coverage" use="string(ancestor-or-self::coverage[locationNumber]/locationNumber)" />`

Comment: **1.** I don't know *exactly* how it works "under the hood". I believe it creates an index, and it's certainly a lot faster in practice - AFAIK, that's true for practically any processor. . Which specific processor are you using?  **2.** I have edited my answer to extend the key to ancestor coverage's locations (quite similar to your own solution). **3.** I don't see that using XSLT 2.0 would be any different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this approach is efficient enough - using a template that matches every `location` with a `number` matching a `locationNumber` child element of `locationSplits`

```
<xsl:template match="location[number=//coverage//locationNumber]">
```

and a second template matching every other `location`, the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="insuranceCoverages">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="location[number=//coverage//locationNumber]">
      <xsl:variable name="number" select="number" />
      <xsl:text>Location</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$number" />
      <xsl:text>Coverage:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="//locationSplits//coverage[locationNumber=$number]/name" />
      <xsl:for-each select="//locationSplits//coverage[locationNumber=$number]/clauses/coverage">
        <xsl:text>Coverage:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="location">
    <xsl:variable name="number" select="number" />
    <xsl:text>Location</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$number" />
    <xsl:text>No Location</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//insuranceCoverages//coverage[not(ancestor::locationSplits)]">
      <xsl:text>Coverage:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML produces the output

```
Location 1
Coverage: Building Coverage
Coverage: Earthquake Exclusion
Location 2
No Location
Coverage: General Coverage
Coverage: General Liability
```

I'm not sure if multiple clauses for coverages in `locationSplits` are possible, so maybe it's not necessary to loop over them.
The template matching `location` without a `coverage` in `locationSplits` just prints every `coverage` child element of `insurangeCoverages` that is no child element of `locationSplits`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//insuranceCoverages//coverage[not(ancestor::locationSplits)]">
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I appreciate that you transformed your output into text, though that was an unintentional cue on my part. The output should be xml but I understand your algorithm. I'm not an expert on XPath but my understanding is that // commands are expensive because the processor needs to scan the entire document for matches. I'm certain there are shortcuts taken behind the scenes to speed these up but I'm looking for a best practice approach.